# How to add an entry to chrome browser dns cache list (changing the source code)

Tags: c, google-chrome

I have been working on chrome source for a while and I am making some changes for performance test.

I am interested in adding new DNS entries to chrome cache, so that it shows up in `chrome://net-internals/#dns`

I have a hard time to find the right flow in the source code.

Can someone with experience please help?

I found the dns resolver code in `/net/base/dnsrr_resolver.cc`
This is where the dns reolution occurs, however, I am interested in manually inserting dns entries without making a resolution call.

Comment: Why do you need this? If it is for testing, why don't you add a host entry in your OS. (Say /etc/hosts in a *nix).

Comment: The thing is we are prototyping some changes in the browser and underlying network transactions. Eventually I would like the browser to run regardless of Operating system.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up modifying the code in net/base/host_resolve_proc.cc. This is where the system call for resolving happens. If the address list is updated with new resolution entries, the browser would update it's host cache with the new resolution.